# Why is vs code saying the method '.getDocuments' and the getter documents are not defined for types Query and QuerySnapshot respectively?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
void _getQuestions() async {
    // Query Firestore for questions with the specified tags
    Query query = await _firestore
        .collection('questions')
        .where('tags', arrayContainsAny: widget.tags);
        QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await query.getDocuments();
    setState(() {
      _questions = querySnapshot.documents;
    });
```

importing cloud_firestore.dart.

I expected the errors to leave, but they are still around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method to get the documents is called `get()` in Flutter, not `getDocuments()`.

I recommend keeping the Firebase documentation handy for this sort of thing, for this case that'd be the section on [getting multiple documents from a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#dart_4)